# Tomcat: War file deploys locally but not on online server

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I've a war file of a web app that runs on tomcat 8 via netbeans as well as tomcat 8 independently without IDE. But if I try to run the same war file on tomcat 8 installed in an online server(I'm using koding.com vm for the purpose), I'm getting the following log in catalina.out:

```
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.458 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.459 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Oct 7 2015 18:25:21 UTC
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.460 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.28.0
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.460 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.460 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.13.0-29-generic
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.460 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.460 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.461 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b14
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.461 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.461 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /home/stutech/tomcat
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.461 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /home/stutech/tomcat
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.462 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/stutech/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.462 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.462 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/stutech/tomcat/endorsed
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.462 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/stutech/tomcat
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.463 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/stutech/tomcat
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.463 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/stutech/tomcat/temp
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.463 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.731 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.782 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.788 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.794 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.796 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1307 ms
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.880 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.961 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /home/stutech/tomcat/webapps/Whiteboard.war
19-Oct-2015 04:47:21.979 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
19-Oct-2015 04:47:23.573 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Whiteboard]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [register] and [com.whiteboard.servlet.register] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/register] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2024)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1918)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1913)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1913)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1913)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1139)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5080)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

19-Oct-2015 04:47:23.575 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive /home/stutech/tomcat/webapps/Whiteboard.war
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Whiteboard]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

19-Oct-2015 04:47:23.584 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /home/stutech/tomcat/webapps/Whiteboard.war has finished in 1,615 ms
19-Oct-2015 04:47:23.585 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/stutech/tomcat/webapps/docs
19-Oct-2015 04:47:23.918 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /home/stutech/tomcat/webapps/docs has finished in 333 ms
19-Oct-2015 04:47:23.922 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/stutech/tomcat/webapps/examples
19-Oct-2015 04:47:24.499 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /home/stutech/tomcat/webapps/examples has finished in 577 ms
19-Oct-2015 04:47:24.499 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/stutech/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
19-Oct-2015 04:47:24.529 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /home/stutech/tomcat/webapps/host-manager has finished in 30 ms
19-Oct-2015 04:47:24.533 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/stutech/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
19-Oct-2015 04:47:24.567 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /home/stutech/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 33 ms
19-Oct-2015 04:47:24.567 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/stutech/tomcat/webapps/manager
19-Oct-2015 04:47:24.626 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /home/stutech/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 59 ms
19-Oct-2015 04:47:24.641 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
19-Oct-2015 04:47:24.656 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
19-Oct-2015 04:47:24.660 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 2863 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named
>   [register] and [com.whiteboard.servlet.register] are both mapped to
>   the url-pattern [/register] which is not permitted

This Error clearly states that same `url-mapping` is mapped to two Servlets.

Modify your `web.xml` and you are good to go.

Comment: I understand that and was thinking the same thing, but why is the same war file running locally without any errors?